# Unable to dynamically create parent-child tkinter widgets in python

Tags: python, tkinter

I am playing around with tkinter by creating a mortgage calculator. I am trying to create widgets dynamically from a separate file which contains lists with the relevant attributes.

The main file is:

```
import tkinter as tk
import tkinter.ttk as ttk

import tkinterwidgetinfo as twi

root=tk.Tk()
root.title('Tkinter Practice')

class Application(ttk.Frame):
    def __init__(self, master=None):
        super().__init__()
        self.pack()
        self.createApplication()

    def createApplication(self):
        ## create widgets dynamically from twi
        for i in twi.progWidgets:
            a = i[1]+i[2]+'**'+str(i[3])+')'
            i[0] = eval(a)
            i[0].pack()

app = Application(root)
app.mainloop()
```

The list containing the widget information is in a separate file and imported. The information is as follows:

```
progWidgets = [
    ['inputFrame', 'ttk.LabelFrame(', '', {'text': "User Input",
                                           'labelanchor': "nw"}],
    ['principalLabel', 'ttk.Label(', 'inputFrame,', {'text' : "Principal(£)"}],
    ['principalEntry', 'ttk.Entry(', 'inputFrame,', {}],
    ['termLabel', 'ttk.Label(', 'inputFrame,', {'text' : "Mortgage Term (Years)"}],
    ['termEntry', 'ttk.Entry(', 'inputFrame,', {}]
    ]
```

When I run this code, the first widget (the labelframe), isn't created. However, when I create the labelframe outside the loop, as follows:

```
import tkinter as tk
import tkinter.ttk as ttk

import tkinterwidgetinfo as twi

root=tk.Tk()
root.title('Tkinter Practice')

class Application(ttk.Frame):
    def __init__(self, master=None):
        super().__init__()
        self.pack()
        self.createApplication()

    def createApplication(self):
        inputFrame = ttk.Labelframe(text = "User Input",
                                    labelanchor = "nw")
        inputFrame.pack()

        ## create widgets dynamically from twi
        for i in twi.progWidgets:
            a = i[1]+i[2]+'**'+str(i[3])+')'
            i[0] = eval(a)
            i[0].pack()

app = Application(root)
app.mainloop()
```

The program behaves perfectly. How can I include the labelframe in the loop?

Comment: Are we supposed to not question the why of using a string list with `eval`?

Comment: Pardon?

I used this approach so I could abstract the parameters into a separate file. I already made a simple working program, I'm now trying to explore other ways of doing the same thing.

Comment: I just think that this approach is impractical(as opposed to an OOP for example), and needs to be emphasized that `eval` is used deliberately for the sake of it. If not a deliberate use I could just answer your question using OOP.

Comment: This is not a good idea. There's simply no good reason to put your code in lists like that. Eventually you'll want to add some custom feature, then another, and then you might as well be writing it in python.

Comment: The reason I did it this way was that the list gives you a sort of 'cms' approach so you can adapt/add/remove widgets without having to trawl through repetitive bits of code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To anyone finding this question, as you can tell from the content I was very new to programming at the time. From what I can remember I was under the naïve impression that organising the code in a very abstract manner was somehow saving processing time or somehow easier to read. I didn't have a grasp of the underlying mechanisms which dictate the operation of computers. With this in mind akarilimano's answer is correct and works but I would support the comments beneath the original question which criticise the use of such a bizarre layout.

### From PEP 20

- Beautiful is better than ugly.
- Explicit is better than implicit.
- Simple is better than complex.
- Readability counts.
- If the implementation is hard to explain, it's a bad idea.

Answer (score 0):

You use `'inputFrame'` as a parent name but it is not defined. When you run your second piece of code `inputFrame` is defined and everything works.

I agree with commenters that using `eval` is a terrible idea (security reasons, flexibility), but you still can do this:

```
for i in twi.progWidgets:
    a = i[0]+'='+i[1]+i[2]+'**'+str(i[3])+')'
    eval(a)
    a = i[0]+'.pack()'
    eval(a)
```